# How to build codebase against multiple versions of an SBT plugin?

Tags: scala, sbt

I've got some projects that I'd like to cross-build for multiple Scalas, which is straightforward, but also for multiple versions of Play! Framework, which is less straightforward because they come as an SBT plugin.

I've currently got it working by separating them into completely separate builds, with symlinks to share a common codebase project. **Is this the best solution or can I do it in a single build?**

I'm aware of the whole "SBT is recursive" thing so I know they are going to have to be separate build projects, but wondered if they could still live within the same aggregated build.

Minimal setup:

https://github.com/halfninja/play-multiversion-build

If this is the best way to go about it then I'll self-answer with this but I'm interested to hear from people with a more SBT-minded brain as it's stretching my comprehension.

I've also seen some builds use system properties to modify versions, which avoids needing separate directories with symlinks but is otherwise the same solution requiring separate builds.